# Rails ActiveRecord :pluck and :map return two different values - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model (using STI) `MonetaryChange::PaymentPromise` that has `subtotal_cents` as an attribute / column (an integer).

My controller is updating that model/attribute, but for some reason, I'm getting the old/original value when I call `map` and the updated (correct) value when I call `pluck`. For example:

```
V410MonetaryChange::PaymentPromise.where(id: 1).pluck(:subtotal_cents)
=> [24600] # this is the correct updated value

V410MonetaryChange::PaymentPromise.where(id: 1).map(&:subtotal_cents)
=> [12300] # this is the original value, but it should have been updated to 24600
```

I notice that the SQL that Rails generates for the `pluck` method is much  simpler:

```
(0.5ms)  SELECT "v410_monetary_changes"."subtotal_cents" 
FROM "v410_monetary_changes" 
WHERE "v410_monetary_changes"."type" IN ('V410MonetaryChange::PaymentPromise') 
AND "v410_monetary_changes"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
AND "v410_monetary_changes"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
```

but the SQL for the `map` method loads a whole bunch of associations after the first query:

```
  V410MonetaryChange::PaymentPromise Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "v410_monetary_changes".* FROM "v410_monetary_changes" WHERE "v410_monetary_changes"."type" IN ('V410MonetaryChange::PaymentPromise') AND "v410_monetary_changes"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "v410_monetary_changes"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
  V410OrderedSku Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "v410_ordered_skus".* FROM "v410_ordered_skus" WHERE "v410_ordered_skus"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "v410_ordered_skus"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  V410OrderedSkusV410Sku Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "v410_ordered_skus_v410_skus".* FROM "v410_ordered_skus_v410_skus" WHERE "v410_ordered_skus_v410_skus"."v410_ordered_sku_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["v410_ordered_sku_id", 1]]
  V410Sku Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "v410_skus".* FROM "v410_skus" WHERE "v410_skus"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

Any idea why this is the case, and how I can resolve this?

I tried adding `.reload` to my query, but the results were the same:

```
V410MonetaryChange::PaymentPromise.where(id: 1).reload.map(&:subtotal_cents)
=> [12300]
```

**Edit 1:**
I can confirm that the database has the correct value (24600). When I open a `psql` console, and run the query:

```
SELECT "v410_monetary_changes"."subtotal_cents" 
    FROM "v410_monetary_changes" 
    WHERE "v410_monetary_changes"."type" IN ('V410MonetaryChange::PaymentPromise') 
    AND "v410_monetary_changes"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
    AND "v410_monetary_changes"."id" = 1;
```

I get:

```
 subtotal_cents 
----------------
          24600
(1 row)
```

So Rails must be doing something with the associations that is causing it to give me an old version of the record. Any ideas why?

Comment: It should be the same. Try restarting your rails console.

Comment: @EvanG - yes, I thought of that too. Sadly restarting the console changes nothing!

Comment: Did you override your `subtotal_cents` in your model?

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej I have two other `subtotal_cents` methods in parent models, but not in the model I am querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, important Rails lesson learned today!

I recently added an `after_initialize` callback to this model, which set the default values (including `subtotal_cents`) for newly initialized records.

What I didn't realise is that this callback was **re**-initializing (ie overwriting in memory after load) **existing** records with the default values.

My fix was to change

```
after_initialize :set_default_currency_amounts
```

to

```
after_initialize :set_default_currency_amounts, unless: Proc.new { |pp| pp.persisted? }
```

In my case, this is why the SQL was so long - my defaults required the loading of some associated models to get the default value for `subtotal_cents`. This was the clue that helped me solve this.

Thank you to everyone for your help!

Comment: I think you are starting to realize that all ActiveRecord callbacks are evil. I'd aim to move the `after_initialize` to a factory which will help to create your record. Running 3 queries by calling `Model.new` is a nasty side effect in my opinion.

Comment: You should be able to say just `unless: :persisted?` or perhaps `if: :new_record?`.